# how to control the marks in \addplot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw some functions and I want to mark the points that I want, example every 1 or every 0.1 and the horizontal axes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-base, pgf, tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
    [
     anchor=center, %%% noodzakelijk om te punten correct te kunnen bepalen.
     major grid style=black,
    grid=both, 
    title= $x(t)$-diagram,
    x=100mm,
    y=100mm,
    xtick={0,0.1,...,0.8}, 
    %minor xtick={0,0.2,...,14},
    xmin=0, xmax=0.8,
    xlabel={\scriptsize $t$(s)},
    ylabel={\scriptsize $x$(m)},
    axis x line=middle,
    ytick={0,0.1,...,0.5},
    minor ytick={0,0.01,...,0.5},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    ymin=0, ymax=0.45,
    axis y line=middle,
    ]
    \addplot[smooth, mark=*,cyan] {1*x};
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center} 
    \end{document}
```

As you can see on the picture it is not ok.
Is it really necessary that I make another `\addplot` with the points?

[image]

Comment: Give the domain correctly. Currently there is only one data point in the visible area. For example, try `domain=0:0.8`

Comment: I've already tried to add domain=0:0.7, but it gives me to many points, and not linked at all to the scale on the x-axe.

Comment: You also need to adjust the `sample` key accordingly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.